# Excel Formula to Get Time Difference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Checking out a formula that can take the difference of the time schedule. I have

```
=ABS(TRIM(LEFT(M2,8))-TRIM(RIGHT(M2,8)))*24
```

but it doesn't take into consideration the hours that will go beyond 12AM (the next day). Example on the second row (4:00 PM - 12:00 AM). I am only interested with the time that it elapsed from the start time to the end time, which is supposed to be 8, but the result is different because of the difference in the date. Any suggestions without adding a date column?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add 1 to the time when it goes to the next day.

```
=IF(MID(M2,FIND("-",M2)+2,LEN(M2))<LEFT(M2,FIND("-",M2)-1),1,0)+MID(M2,FIND("-",M2)+2,LEN(M2))-LEFT(M2,FIND("-",M2)-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott! I'm not sure why in my end it displays a different number. For 8:00 AM - 4:00 PM, I got 1.3333 using your formula. Format is in general.

Comment: Thank you very much, Scott! Very helpful.

Comment: Scott, any way that I can use the [h] format and would still display 8?

Comment: Multiply the whole thing by 24